# Using `combineLatest` with Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular-material2

Trying to use `combineLatest` with the Angular Material `Table`. Trying to combine the `MatPaginator` and the `MatSort` and it is not working.

Here is the [example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) i am following. I am looking at the "Table retrieving data through HTTP" example.

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) private _paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) private _sort: MatSort;

public ngOnInit(): void {

    this._sort.sortChange.subscribe(
        () => {
            console.log("this works");
        }
    );

    combineLatest(
        this._sort.sortChange,
        this._paginator.page
    ).pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(
            () => {
                return this._userService.getAll();
            }
        ),
        tap(
            (users: IUser[]) => {
                this._data = users;
            }
        )
    ).subscribe();
}
```

The problem with the code above is the `combineLatest` observable is only triggered one time when the component is loaded. I would expect it to trigger every time the sorting or pagination is triggered. When i subscribe straight to the `sortChange` it fires every time i change the sorting.

The code above will work when i change `combineLatest` to `merge`. It will work as expected. But i need to combine the latest results from both the sorter and paginator every time either one is changed. But it will not ever fire with `combineLatest`. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are piping the result of `combineLatest` to a `startWith` operator, that will only emit once. Just leave out the `startWith` operator and instead of setting the result in a `tap` operator, use the `subscribe` function, like this:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) private _paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) private _sort: MatSort;

public ngOnInit(): void {

    this._sort.sortChange.subscribe(
        () => {
            console.log("this works");
        }
    );

    merge(combineLatest(
        this._sort.sortChange,
        this._paginator.page), of({}))
    .pipe(switchMap(() => this._userService.getAll()))
    .subscribe((users: IUser[]) => this._data = users);
}
```

Comment: That does not help. I had the `startsWith` there so it will fire once as soon as `ngOnInit` is called. So it will call the `userService`. And moving the other stuff from `tap` really doesn't do anything different than what `subscribe` does for me. I did try your suggestion and it does not work. The `sortChange` and `paginator` do not fire inside the `combineLatest` observable. But it does fire when using `merge` and in the `sortChange` observable above the code.

Comment: are you sure that paginator ever fires? combineLatest will only emit the first time when at least both observables fired at least once.

Comment: I will also update my post to include the requirement for firing a first time on init

Comment: I just added `startsWith({})` to the `_sort` and the `_paginator` and it seems to be working now.